# label inside input text box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a mockup given below, I looked around to find something similar but no luck. Could some one guide me how to do this.

So problem here is need to show static "from" "to" and "90 days" text every time.

**Note** "From","To","days" and Icon should be inside text box

[image]

Comment: Have a look around CodePen. One example here: http://codepen.io/simoberny/pen/gpddYQ

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself? What/where exactly is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "label inside input text box"? It looks like both your dates are separate text boxes sitting inside a div with a black border? Does this basic implementation look like what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/d27zj5hj/

Comment: @dekel Sorry, I didn't know how to kept static text inside text box

Comment: What is a "text box"? A `<textarea>`? An `<input>`? Or a `div` with a border that contains various other elements?

Comment: div or input box
it can be anything @gibberish

Comment: Check out my answer again, NLP. I edited the code to add a border around the outer div, effectively putting the desired elements inside a box. If that is now what you need, please explain further below the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tweak the code from gibberish and see if this serve your purpose.
and for the label inside textbox set placeholder attribute of input tag

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eEa1kEtgK9ZL6h60VXwDsJ2rxYCwfxi40VZ9E0XwoEA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
 $(function() {
            $( ".dp" ).datepicker();
        });


</script>
```

```css
<style>
div{position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}
.row{overflow:hidden;border:2px solid #aaa;padding:5px;}
.r-left {float:left;width:30%;margin-right:10px;}
.r-right{float:left;width:30%;margin:0 10px;}
.farright{float:right;width:30%;margin-left:10px;}
.inlineblock{display:inline-block;color: grey;}
#90days{margin-left:15px;margin-top:-35px;color: red;}

#datFrom{

    border: 0px;
}

#datTo{
border: 0px;

}

.floating-label {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 15px;
   top: 20px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.floating-label1 {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 215px;
   top: 20px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.inputText {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 185px;
    height: 35px;
}

input:focus ~ .floating-label,input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label{
      top: 15px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
    color: grey;
}

input:focus ~ .floating-label1,input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label1{
      top: 15px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 215px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
    color: grey;
}


.calender-css{
height:35px;
vertical-align: middle;

}

input:focus {
border-color:white;

}

</style>
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eEa1kEtgK9ZL6h60VXwDsJ2rxYCwfxi40VZ9E0XwoEA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="r-left">
    <!--<div>FROM</div>-->
    <div><input id="datFrom" class="dp inputText" type="text" required/><span class="floating-label">From</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="r-right">
     <!--<div>TO</div>-->
    <div><input id="datTo" class="dp inputText" type="text" required/><span class="floating-label1">TO</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="farright">
     <div class="inlineblock" id="90days">
       90 days
    </div>
    <div class="inlineblock">
      <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/calendar-icon-png-14.png" class="calender-css" />
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a VERY simple example intended to get you started.

The key point is: use jQuery UI's "datepicker" module. It is powerful - you can auto-calculate the 90 day calc and, upon leaving the Date From field, have it auto-calc 90 days and plunk that date into the From field as a default.

*Look how much you get done with how little.*

```js
$( ".dp" ).datepicker();
/*    */
```

```css
div{position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}
.row{overflow:hidden;border:2px solid #aaa;padding:5px;}
.r-left {float:left;width:33%;margin-right:10px;}
.r-right{float:left;width:33%;margin:0 10px;}
.farright{display:flex;height:50px;}
  .inlineblock{width:60px;height:50px;margin:auto;flex-flow: row nowrap;justify-content:flex-end;align-content:center;}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eEa1kEtgK9ZL6h60VXwDsJ2rxYCwfxi40VZ9E0XwoEA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="r-left">
    <div>FROM</div>
    <div><input id="datFrom" class="dp" type="text" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="r-right">
    <div>TO</div>
    <div><input id="datTo" class="dp" type="text" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="farright">
    <div class="inlineblock">
       <br>90 days
    </div>
    <div class="inlineblock" id="90days">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/nature" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not what I intended to do.. from and to should be inside textbox